# Activate a specific figure when returning from a nested function

Tags: matlab, nested, figure

I have a plotting function inside **`imshow()`** command.

The plot and the image should be in separate figures.

At the return from the inside function the current figure is of the plot thus `imshow()` puts the image onto the same figure of the plot and kills the plot.

**What can be done** to make `imshow()` open or get to an existing its own figure, while keeping such manner of nested function calling?

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what it is you're asking.  Are you saying that you have modified `imshow` to show an additional plot? Can you also show us some code on what it is you're asking about? I think the code will provide a more clearer picture on what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: @rayryeng,  
I have modified nothing, just nested a plotting function inside `imshow()` which upon return activates the figure it has been plotting on, thus `imshow()` outputs to this figure instead of making its own one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I've found an answer:

1. open a figure before `imshow(nested_function());`
2. upon starting the `nested_function()` save the handle to the
   previous figure like `fh_prev = gcf;` for example
3. do any plots along the `nested_function()`
4. before return from the `nested_function()` activate the previous
   figure with the command `figure(fh_prev);`